# How do run javascript after loading PartialView in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery plug-in meioMask to work in a MVC Partial View.

As a trial, the following works:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.meio.mask.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#StartTimeText').setMask('time');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="StartTimeText" />
</body>
```

The text edit box gets a mask edit applied. However, my text edit box is in a MVC partial view that gets shown when user clicks on an item in the main view. In the main view's `<head>` I added the following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.meio.mask.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In `CustomFormPartialView.cshtml`, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.ajax(
      function ($) {
        $('#StartTimeText').setMask('time');
      }
    );
</script>

<input type="text" id="StartTimeText" />
```

But the text box remains a regular text box with no edit mask applied. I assume this is because the setMask function isn't getting run. I've tried using `jQuery.get` and `jQuery.post` as well, none of them made any difference.

Sorry if this has already been asked, I've tried other solutions without any luck. I'm a bit new in this area, so if someone can post as complete code example as possible it'll be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Following JasCav's suggestion, I've put the following in the `<head>` section of the file. As far as I can tell, the ajax function isn't getting run at all. This is using DevExpress's MVC Scheduler if that's any help. I'm not getting any errors in FireBug.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/WebTMS_MVC/Calendar/SchedulerPartial',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
      $('#StartTimeText').setMask('time');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's ajax function provides a number of callbacks that you can use to perform specific actions after completion of the ajax call (success and complete are two). See more at [jQuery's documentation for the ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: yourUrl,
  type: "GET",
  data: formData,
  success: function(data) {
    // Do your stuff here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, still not working unfortunately. I've edited my original question to post the changes I made.